# Safari WebRTC with easyrtc

Tags: safari, webrtc, easyrtc

On Chrome, I'm getting full Webcam & Microphone support both ways with easyrtc.js, but Safari doesn't want to cooperate.

The latest version of Safari is listed as being WebRTC compatible (https://webkit.org/blog/7627/safari-technology-preview-32/).  In addition, I have the option to "Enable Legacy WebRTC API" under the Develop menu.

Without `Legacy WebRTC API` enabled, I get the error message from easyrtc `Your browser doesn't appear to support WebRTC.`  After enabling it, I get the error message `Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Type error` from the easyrtc.js `this.createObjectURL` function at: `window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream)`.

Any ideas how to get Safari to behave like the Chrome version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced the same problem with easyrtc then  used beta branch of easyrtc in development and it works. Previous, was using master branch.

beta branch includes `playsinline` for safari.

Clone their `beta` branch using :

`git clone -b <branchName> <repository>`
means

`git clone -b beta https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc.git`

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I know nothing about easyrtc.js*

It looks like easyrtc relies on an older version of the WebRTC API to detect WebRTC compatibility, which explains why the Legacy option "gets you further".

As far as the promise error goes: `this.createObjectURL` has been deprecated for quite a while in favour of `srcObject` assignment.

> Any ideas how to get Safari to behave like the Chrome version?

You probably won't get them to behave alike. *But* I would recommend you checkout [adapter](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) and include it in your project. This is a project which tries to eliminate these kinds of API differences between browser vendors until the API has been stabilised.